# Why I can not install Google Chrome?

Tags: installation, uninstall, google-chrome

I am in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32bit environment, and if I want to install Chrome (32bit), the system would inform me that:

```
yao@yao-ThinkPad-X220:~/download$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb 
[sudo] password for yao: 
dpkg：solve google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb (--install) error：
 google-chrome-stable: 22.0.1229.92-r159988 (Multi-Arch: no) is not co-installable with google-chrome-stable:amd64 22.0.1229.92-r159988 (Multi-Arch: no) which is currently installed
```

I promise I never installed any Chrome. I also try to remove Chrome but the Ubuntu system tells me that it can not find Chrome.

So, please help me, thanks.

Comment: How come it's Chrome 22?

Answer (score 1):

it seems to be that Chrome 64-bit is already installed.

I think it would be easy to check your software-resources if there's a mention of Chrome (you can find that out on the second tab 'other software')

If so, open softwarecenter and install the pack Synaptic (a handy program for all purposes)

After installation open Synaptic and type in the search-box 'Chrome'

You can see, if there's a package installed, some fields concerning Chrome (or Google Chrome) marked on the left side as green (indication that it's on your system) . 
Click there and mark it for **complete removal** , after the removal is over and done, you can try to install again Chrome (but the 32-bits version)

May I mention that you can easilly install Chromium from the softwarecenter ? They are virtually the same and will give you no headache to install it ;) , updates included. 
Just a suggestion.

Comment: Yes, you can get "chromium-browser 24.0.1312.56" just by a simple `sudo apt-get install`. But I get Google Chrome direct from Google as I describe [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/264574/25656) and the process is pretty goof-proof. And the Chrome version I have is 25.0.1364.152. The updates are done just the same as any other software.